# Has anyone done an english translation for the song 致你 by yihuik 苡慧

Tags: mandarin, simplified-characters

I found a translation of the chorus of the song online and it seems to be just a google translate, and so I wonder if there is perhaps a better way to understand the meaning of the song. Anyway, I have quoted below a translation for the chorus that I have, and I wonder if anyone has anything better. If someone has the whole song translated, then that is great.

*If miss is a withered cloud

Blowing to you in the wind

Landed in your ear and whispered

Like a silent typewriter

Full of enthusiasm

I can't write, I will leave, I love you too much

To the end

I have to be careful

Try to sneak in

Touch your transparent heart

Guess your unsealed expression

Only dare to write the opening

To you*

Is it saying:
*I miss you. I can't say it but I will leave. I will write a note but all I can write is "dear you"*

Comment: Found this, https://lyricstranslate.com/en/zhì-nǐ-dear-you.html, don't know if that helps. If you want to understand the meaning of the song, it may be better if you take a specific sentence out and we could explain.

Comment: Well, I wonder if the chorus part is translated with proper meaning. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Is it saying: I miss you. I can't say it but I will leave. I will write a note but all I can write is "dear you"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, lemme quickly explain this song.
To my understanding, this song is about a woman/man who fell in love with a person, but because of reasons couldn't say "I love you" to his/her lover in person, so the narrator decided to write a love letter in the form of this song.

The chorus of the song is kinda saying like I really love you, but I don't have the guts to say it; in the end, when I was thinking about you (how you would feel when you open the love letter"猜你启封的表情"), I had the courage to write down "To my dearest lover:" (as in the start of a letter).

This start of the letter may be what confused you, the word choice is not exactly as what we write in Chinese （but we kinda understand）. 致你 I believe as in like 致我最亲爱的人 at the start of the letter, or like "Dear XXXX" in English, or perhaps 致XXX on the envelope.

If one were to directly translate, then I believe the translation is mostly correct but certain parts of it are very correct (like the typewriter part).

I'll just quickly give you a brief idea of the song's meaning:

So from "恋恋不舍" to "不知去往何方", I love this person, who is filling the void of my loneliness, I dunno how to express my love.

From "支离破碎" to "不经意的设防", I've been hurt before, I am a little defensive so I can't directly express my love.

"跌跌宕宕" to "穿梭在无人演出的剧场": I keep thinking about you in my head.

"若想念是凋谢的云" to "写不出 会别离 太爱你": I have a crush on you. (Silently whisper like the clouds in a wind or a jammed typewriter that couldn't type the love letter)

"到最后" to "只敢写下开篇的 致你": So in the end, I could only think about how happy you'll be (despite not knowing how the other might react)) and then start my love letter

Comment: Wow, thanks. I wouldn't have guessed any of that meaning. The translation does not seem to be even close to that. Particularly the first part of the chorus, the first three lines I thought meant "missing you" just finds a way to land back to me on my ear.